# VBScript / Classic ASP - How do I Check If a Property Exists in An Object Without Throwing an Error

Tags: asp-classic

**Sample Code:**

```
Dim myObject
Set myObject = JSON.parse(someJsonResponseFromTheServer)    

myFunction(myObject.someProperty)
```

**The Problem:**

When code similiar to this is ran in my application, it throws a `500` error from the server with a message similar to "Object Does not support property or method 'someProperty'. What I would like to do to solve this problem is something like this:

```
Dim myObject
Set myObject = JSON.parse(someJsonResponseFromTheServer)    

If myObject.someProperty Then
    myFunction(myObject.someProperty)
End If
```

However, if I add the conditional, it throws the same error on the line with the conditional instead of the line with the method call.

**My Question:**

In ASP Classic, how do you detect if a property exists within an object without throwing an error?

Comment: Natively ASP does not have a json parser.  What are your using to get a JSON implementation into ASP?

Comment: @AnthonyWJones, Good question. Given that I just started this project (and job) like 3 days ago, I'm not quite sure how they are doing it.

Comment: There are two JSON for ASP Classic implementations. From json.org: [aspjson](http://code.google.com/p/aspjson/) and [JSON ASP utility class](http://www.webdevbros.net/2007/04/26/generate-json-from-asp-datatypes/). The last one is no longer maintained.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones Like VBScript, JavaScript can also be run on the server side just like Node.js using the classic ASP engine.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One of the benefits of classic ASP is that it allows you to run both VBScript and JScript **in the same page** - thus you can use the power of both.

First, add this block of JScript code to your existing `.asp` file:

```
<script language="JScript" runat="server">
function CheckProperty(obj, propName) {
    return (typeof obj[propName] != "undefined");
}
</script>
```

And assuming VBScript is the default language in the page, you can call it from within your VBScript code like this:

```
Dim myObject
Set myObject = JSON.parse(someJsonResponseFromTheServer)    
If CheckProperty(myObject, "someProperty") Then
    myFunction(myObject.someProperty)
End If
```

Tested it with generic class object and it works fine - the JScript is compiled before the VBScript thus accessible to it.

Comment: Be carefull though, combining JavaScript and VBScript. Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10083632/call-a-function-written-on-vb-from-a-jscript-code-classic-asp) SO thread for some very important things to note.

Comment: @Guido as long as VBScript is the default it should work just fine: "The non-default language scripts are parsed and executed first... By the time the default language script is parsed and executed all the global identifiers created by the previous language scripts **will have been added to the script environment and are therefore available for use from inline code**"

Comment: Shadow Wizard, thanks, this will indeed work perfect. I wanted to point Levi on possible issues when combining the two.

Comment: Six years later and this is still gold. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

Sadly, this usually means an 'on error' statement.

```vbs
Private Function TestProperty()
    Dim Success
    Success = False

    On Error Resume Next
        ' set for property here
        Success = (Err.Number = 0)
    On Error Goto 0
    TestProperty = Success
Exit Function
```

Answer (score 5):

On the assumption that you are including some runat="server" js file that provides you with the JSON parser then `JSON.parse` is going to return a Javascript object.

If the above assumption is correct then the following ought to work:

```
If myObject.hasOwnProperty("someProperty") Then 
    myFunction(myObject.someProperty) 
End If
```