# Call server side vb code from js (asp classic)

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, vbscript

I have code written in server side VB.

```
<script language="vbscript" runat="server">
Function SomeMethod()
   ....
End Function 
</script>
```

How I can call this piece of code from javascript part of server side code?

```
 <script language="javascript" runat="server">
    //some code

    var a = SomeMethod();

 </script>
```

When I try to call VB function the next error occurs.

Microsoft JScript runtime error '800a138f'
Object expected

Thank you!

Comment: All parts of code runs at the server side.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using VBScript function in JScript when Language=VBScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12174692/using-vbscript-function-in-jscript-when-language-vbscript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is essentially the same question as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12174692/25163), though the focus is more on the order of execution side of things. ASP will execute the scripts in different order, depending on the language and syntax:

1. global.asa
2. server-side includes
3. Javascript tagged with `<script>` tags
4. HTML together with scripts tagged within `<% %>` delimiters
5. VBscript tagged within `<script>` tags

More information can be found at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260861%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) and [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Classic_ASP_Design_Mistakes).